# Angular Error asignando "*" a una variable declarada en el scope

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo declarado en el scope la siguiente variable :

```
  $scope.submit={
     next:"",
     formparams:"",
     value:""
  };
```

En mi HTML tengo :

```
  <div>
   <div ng-repeat="opcion in menu.opciones"><label> Opcion: </label>
     <input id="{{opcion.opcion}}" type="radio" name=grupo
      value="{{opcion.Submit}}+{{opcion.opcion}}" ng-model="submit.next"
      ng-change="submit.value={{opcion.opcion}}" ng-required="true"required> {{opcion.opcion}}                          
    </input>
</div></div>
```

En el arreglo de opciones vienen un arreglo de la siguiente manera `{1,2,3,4,*,#}`

Cuando selecciono en el radio cualquiera de las opciones que sean numéricas todo perfecto, pero cuando selecciono ejemplo el "*"  en la consola del navegador veo el siguiente error :

```
angular.js:9419 TypeError: a is not a function
at OPERATORS.* (http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:9515:44)
at http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:10041:35
at Scope.$eval (http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:11961:28)
at http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:16943:13
at http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:16784:11
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:303:11)
at $setViewValue (http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:16782:7)
at http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:16284:14
at Scope.$eval (http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:11961:28)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9419(anonymous function) @ angular.js:6843(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16786forEach @ angular.js:303$setViewValue @ angular.js:16782(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16284Scope.$eval @ angular.js:11961Scope.$apply @ angular.js:12061(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16283(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2613forEach @ angular.js:310eventHandler @ angular.js:2612
```

Y el valor de la opcion "*" no se asigana a la variable.

Muchas gracias por su pronta ayuda.

Comment: ¿Pones el asterisco entrecomillado (`"*"`) o sin las comillas? En el texto de la pregunta lo pones con comillas, pero luego en el ejemplo del arreglo lo pones sin comillas. Y la misma pregunta aplica para la almohadilla (`#`), ¿con comillas o sin ellas?¿falla si seleccionas ese valor?

Comment: Alvaro, coloco el asterisco como esta dentro del arreglo sin comillas.

Comment: ¿Y si le pones las comillas funciona? Es que me imagino que lo que quieres es que el valor sea "*" (como cadena); pero sin comillas, * es el operador de multiplicación y creará problemas

Comment: Alvaro , si tienes toda la razon, el valor del  * lo estaba tomando como un operador no como un string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error estaba en que al colocar el * se estaba interpretando como un operador aritmetico no como un valor de tipo string. al crear el arreglo entonces `['1','2','3','*']` ya funciona el código tal cual como lo tengo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en el array:

```
{1,2,3,4,*,#}
```

Con los números funciona sin problemas, porque se interpretan como un valor entero, pero si quieres que el valor de la opción se "*", tienes que entrecomillar el asterisco; si no, se interpretará como el operador de multiplicación y te crea los problemas que estás viendo. De manera similar, tienes que entrecomillar la almohadilla para que se interprete como una cadena y evitar problemas:

```
{1,2,3,4,"*","#"}
```